# Is this a bug in bash ?(up arrow)

Tags: linux, bash

As we know, press up arrow key can show history commands,but i found that when a command which starting with space will not show in "up arrow"'s history:

`$ls`

`$(press up arrow key)`

bash will show:

`$ls`

however:

`$ps`

`$ ls(notice this command starts with a space)`

now i press up arrow key,it will show 'ps' but not 'ls':

`$ps`

Is this a bug in bash or a specific feature?:)

Comment: +1 cool, that's like 'Private Browsing' in Firefox, didn't notice it before, wonder if the command is still recorded somewhere

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/48778 should answer your question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `bash(1)`:

```
   HISTCONTROL
          A colon-separated list of values controlling how
          commands are saved on the history list.  If the list
          of values includes ignorespace, lines which begin with
          a space character are not saved in the history list.
```

It's an intentional feature to let you prevent commands with passwords or other private data from being saved to disk. (It won't keep it out of the `ps(1)` process listing.)